# Como instalar mongodb en php

Tags: php, mongodb

Bueno llevo tiempo intentado solucionar esto y imposible , intento conectar mongodb a php.

Imagen de la version de php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Los pasos que hago son:

Descargo el dll en este caso uso este : php_mongo-1.6.8-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll

Luego lo renombro a php_mongo.dll

Luego lo pongo en php/ ext

Luego lo añado la extension en el php.ini _= extension=php_mongodb.dll;

Luego reinicio el appserv y nada no aparece ni en la info del php. alguna solucion ?

Comment: Puede ser que estás cambiando mal el archivo .ini , también para descargar la DLL de mongodb es por versión de PHP ten cuidado en eso

Comment: Ya lo arregle ..

Comment: puedes agregar tu solucion

Comment: Tengo otra pregunta es posible usar template engines en php ?

Comment: Si tenes una solucion, agrega la solucion por favor, contestar tus propias preguntas es valido. Si tenes otra pregunta, hacela en el sitio. Mira [ask] y [tour]